# DI, юнит-тесты и autofac. Как организовать корректно тестирование?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, юнит-тесты, dependency-injection

Пытаюсь использовать на проекте `DI` и `autofac`, в том числе при юнит-тестировании.

Если внедрять зависимости "руками", то всё понятно - делаем интерфейсы, передаем в конструкторы и работаем. Однако, хочется избавиться от кучи лишних параметров в конструкторах + задавать соответствие классов - интерфейсам более гибко. Попробовал подключить `autofac`, но к сожалению, пока не понял как при его помощи наиболее оптимально организовать работу.

Есть контейнер:

```
public class IoсContainer
{
    public static IoсContainer Global { get; set; }

    private readonly IContainer _container;

    public IoсContainer(IContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    public T Resolve<T>()
    {
        return _container.Resolve<T>();
    }

    public IContainer GetContainer()
    {
        return _container;
    }
}
```

Контейнер инициализируется и регистрируются зависимости на старте приложения. Дальше в коде он используется следующим образом:

```
IoсContainer.Global.Resolve<IOldImport>().GetUserLists()
```

Вроде всё хорошо. Дальше на метод, содержащий вызов этого контейнера, пишу юнит-тест. Для юнит-теста `Moq`-аю другую реализацию `IOldImport.GetUserLists()`.

```
var testAuth = new Mock<IOldImport>();

testAuth.Setup(
    a => a.GetUserLists(It.IsAny<User>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<RepositoryContainer>()))
    .Returns(new List<UserList>());

var cb = new ContainerBuilder();
cb.RegisterInstance(testAuth.Object).As<IOldImport>();

var container = cb.Build();

IoсContainer.Global = new IoсContainer(container);

AccountController.InitiateDatabaseForNewUser("Tester");
```

Вот тут возникает вопрос - как правильно зарегистрировать новый класс чтобы `IocContainer` его "нашел"? Выше - я просто выставляю новое значение `static` объекту. Но, тесты, как я понимаю, могут выполняться в несколько потоков и в таком случае всё полетит к чертям. Ну и вообще глобальный `static` - фу. Хочется делать что-то вроде:

```
using(var scope = cb.BeginNewLifetimeScope())
{
     AccountController.InitiateDatabaseForNewUser("Tester");
}
```

и чтобы всё дерево вызовов внутри для разрешения интерфейсов использовала указанный контейнер.

Есть ли такая возможность? Или для этого придётся обязательно в каждый метод/конструктор класса передавать IoC-контейнер через параметры?

P.S.: Речь не обязательно про `autofac`, любой аналогичный фреймворк - `Ninject`, `Windsor` и пр. Речь именно про методологию работы.

Comment: не отвечая на вопрос, но всё же, я рекомендую Вам прочитать книгу Mark Seemann Dependency Injection. Там есть ответы на все вопросы, которые у Вас возникнут по DI. Там же Вы найдёте объяснение, почему Вы неправильно использует IoC контейнер.

Answer (score 1):

Тот паттерн, который вы используете, называется не "Dependency Injection", а "Service Locator". Зачастую Service Locator считается антипаттерном, поскольку имеет тенденцию скрывать зависимости в коде.

При правильной реализации IoC через DI, ваши классы вообще не должны знать про контейнеры. Так, чтобы использовать `IOldImport` вам надо принять такой параметр в конструкторе и сохранить в переменную:

```
class SomeClass {
  private readonly IOldImport oldImport;

  public SomeClass(IOldImport oldImport) {
    this.oldImport = oldImport;
  }

  // ...

  public void Foo() {
    // ...
    oldImport.GetUserLists();
    // ...
  }
}
```

Теперь, если запросить у контейнера `SomeClass` - контейнер сам найдет для него реализацию `IOldImport` и передаст в конструктор.

При хорошей реализации про контейнер во всей программе должны знать один-три класса (не считая служебных, вроде модулей в Autofac).

Comment: К сожалению не очень понятно как применить этот пример кода к вопросу. Тут всё-так вопрос как организовать  инфраструктуру, а не конкретно как воспользоваться уже подключённым DI.

Comment: @LiashenkoV если воспользоваться DI так, как написано - никаких проблем с инфраструктурой не будет. Класс `IoсContainer` просто пропадет вместе с порожденными им проблемами.

Comment: Поэтому автор спрашивает, как организовать "методологию работы". У вас указана только одна сторона и так очевидная для @LbISS. Более того в самом заголовке указан вопрос - Как организовать корректно тестирование?... Да и код следовало бы отформатировать, согласно формата вопроса.

Answer (score 1):

Как заметил @PavelMayorov основной роблемой в описанной выше логике является использование статического поля которое используется как сервис локатор. Оно ограничивает вас в тестах и может привести к гонке потоков в многопоточном приложении.

> Если внедрять зависимости "руками", то всё понятно - делаем интерфейсы, передаем в конструкторы и работаем. Однако, хочется избавиться от кучи лишних параметров в конструкторах + задавать соответствие классов - интерфейсам более гибко.

В данном случае вы избавляясь от "лишнего кода", вместе с ним ещё и избавляетесь от слабой связи, так как у вас о соответствии интерфейса объекту будет знать не только [корень композиции](https://github.com/sebas77/Svelto.ECS/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C-%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8) ещё и код обеспечивающий "гибкое соответствие", что может привести к ошибкам.

Почти для каждого типа проекта у autofaq есть [своя интеграция](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/index.html). Для интеграции в конкретно твой проект потребуется небольшое дополнительное усилие.

Если вас беспокоит количество параметров в классе (обычно это не проблема), есть ещё варианты пробросить объект:

- [поле](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/prop-method-injection.html#property-injection)
- [метод](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/prop-method-injection.html#method-injection)
- [окружающий контекст](https://aabs.wordpress.com/2007/12/31/the-ambient-context-design-pattern-in-net/) но это выходит за рамки твоего вопроса.

Для тестов же юзай [Auto-mocking Container](http://www.lshnk.me/avto-mok-konteiner-ot-mark-seemann.html) и не придётся городить лишний код.

Auto-mocking Container (автомок) - это такой комбайн узкозаточенный под юнит тесты, соединяющий в себе функционал DI контейнера и тестового мока. В тестах ты можешь взять этот комбайн и попросить у него SUT c замоканными зависимостями. Причём все зависимости будут тебе доступны для настройки и проверки. Вот взгляни на пример использования:

```
[Fact]
public void PostSendsCorrectEvent()
{
    ...
    // обьект container в данном случае настроен как автомок
    var sut = container.Resolve<BasketController>();
    var item = new BasketItemModel { ProductId = 1234, Quantity = 3 };

    sut.Post(item);
    var expected = item.AddToBasket();

    container
        .Resolve<Mock<ICommandChannel>>()
        .Verify(c => c.Send(expected));
}
```

В англоязычной статье от [Mark Seemann](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/03/11/auto-mocking-container/) это описывается ещё детальнее. Так-же есть перевод см TLDR.